# Show that $F[G]$ is isomorphic to $F[x]/(x^n - 1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebras

Let me start by saying I know that there are similar problems on here but none that give any real sense of direction or understanding, at least for me.

Let $F$ be a field such that $\text{char} (F)=p > 0$ and $G$ a finite cyclic group of order $n$.

Show that $F[G]$ is isomorphic to $F[x]/(x^n - 1)$ as an $F$-algebra,
and find the Jacobson radical of $F[G]$.

I believe that I've shown that these are isomorphic as $F$ algebras. I however feel like I don't have any idea how this then helps me find the Jacobson radical. I know that it is the intersection of maximal left ideals but don't know if this is the right way to go about it or if it is how to find those ideals.

Comment: Note $G$ is cyclic group which implies it is abelian. You would hope $F[G]$ is commutative algebra. First show $F[x]\to F[G]$ by sending $x\to g$ where $g$ is generator of $G$ is surjection. Now $F[x]$ is PID. Check kernel=(x^n-1) via monic property of this polynomial. Since $F[x]$ is PID, you know the prime ideals of $F[x]/(x^n-1)$ are exactly those lying above prime factors of $x^n-1$. Since $char(F)=p$, $x^n-1=(x^m-1)^a$ with $p\mid a$ for some $a$. Find such maximal $a$. Then ask factorization of $x^m-1$.

Comment: So for $h(x)= \prod_j q_j(x)$ square-free, what are the maximal ideals and radical of $F[x]/(h(x)^l)$

Comment: @user45765 That makes sense for the most part, but what do you mean by "those lying above"? And why should a have some maximal? This may be an obvious question but I don't see why we can't just have $p, p^2, p^3, \dots$. Although I guess my intuition is telling me the maximal of these would be $p$ since $F[x]/(x^n-1)^{p^n}\subseteq F[x]/(x^n-1)^p$ if $n>1$.

Comment: $F[x]/(x^n-1)$ is commutative ring. So every proper idea lies in a maximal ideal by zorn lemma. Furthermore, $F[x]$ being PID forces this quotient ring being PID. Hence you know the maximal ideals are those exactly lying above $(x^n-1)$.(i.e. All prime factors over $F[x]$.) $char(F)=p$. So you cannot have $p,p^2,\dots$.(Note that other prime $q$ are invertible.) I am not sure what you mean by $p,p^2,\dots$ here. $F[x]/(x^n-1)^{p^n}$ is not embeded in $F[x]/(x^n-1)^p$ as it is defined by canonical quotient map.